# HTML5 Javascript Nested If Else Is Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, html

Problem: detectLocationtimersset() logic does not seem to work. I know the sub routine is fired but I guess the multiple if else is wrong ?

The the reason for detectLocationtimersset() was to have some logic to ensure multiple timers are not set.

I created the 1st if / else to set the timers based on datatime first then I wrote a second if / else to do the sense check.

detectLocation() has been tested and works in its own right.

```
var detectLocationtimerset = 0;
var datatime = 1;

function detectLocationtimersset() {    
    // Setup timer to check for new data start
    // check and see if set 
    if (detectLocationtimerset = 0 ) {
        detectLocationtimerset = 1;
        if (datatime == null) {
            datatime = 9;
            milliseconds = (datatime * 60000)
            setInterval(function () {
                detectLocation();
                console.log("detectLocation() timer set");
            }, milliseconds);   
        } else {
                    detectLocationtimerset = 1;
            milliseconds = (datatime * 60000)
            setInterval(function () {
                detectLocation();
                console.log("detectLocation() timer set");
            }, milliseconds);   
        }   
    }
};
```

Comment: What is it doing that you do not expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is, but

```
if (detectLocationtimerset = 0 )
```

should probably be

```
if (detectLocationtimerset === 0)
```

On other notes,

- your indentation should be consistent
- your spacing around operators should be consistent
- you should prefer [identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use) over equality wherever possible
- you should move shared code out of the if/else block — put the `milliseconds` assignment and `setInterval` call *after* the `if (datatime == null)` block

Comment: Good catch! I overlooked that twice :)

Comment: Q: What does = & == & === do thats different ? I thought == was to be an exact match  so not 100% sure about ===. T

Comment: @TerranBrown === is the exact match.

Comment: Thanks - tested and working so closed. T

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
if (detectLocationtimerset = 0 ) {
```

should be

```
if (detectLocationtimerset === 0 ) {
```